# Peewee how to add a variable to a specific user Telegram bot API

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

Я пытаюсь помещать данные конкретному пользователю в строку, но как то не получается. Я перечитал документацию, ничего не нашел, я все еще учусь, пожалуйста, помогите в письменной форме, а не ссылку)

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('users.db')


 class BaseModel(Model):
     class Meta:
         database = db


 class Users(BaseModel):
     user_id = IntegerField(unique=True)
     ref = IntegerField(default=0)


@classmethod
def get_user(cls, user_id):
    return cls.get(cls.user_id == user_id)



@classmethod
def get_ref_count(cls, user_id):
    return cls.get(cls.user_id==user_id).ref

@classmethod
def increase_ref_count(cls, user_id):
    user = cls.get_user(user_id)
    user.ref += 1
    user.save()

@classmethod
def user_exists(cls, user_id):
    query = cls().select().where(cls.user_id == user_id)
    return query.exists()

@classmethod
def create_user(cls, user_id):
    user, created = Users.get_or_create(user_id = user_id)
```

Во второй части уже вздор. Я сам писал) Я пытаюсь получить user_id и записать его номер, но я не могу его записать.

qiwi_adr - это переменная, заданная пользователем
они должны быть связаны

| user_id | ref count | number phone |

```
@classmethod
def get_val(cls, user_id):
    return cls.get(cls.qiwi_adr == qiwi_adr)

@classmethod
def val_exists(cls, user_id):
    query = cls().select().where(cls.user_id == qiwi_adr)
    return query.exists()

@classmethod
def get_val(cls, user_id):
    return cls.get(cls.user_id==user_id).qiwi_adr

@classmethod
def create_val(cls, user_id):
    user = cls.get_val(user_id)
    user.qiwi_adr == qiwi_adr
    user.save()
```

Comment: Это Stack overflow на русском языке.
Напишите, пожалуйста, вопрос на русском языке.

Comment: я писал даже не смотрели(